# I cannot create a database in android

Tags: android

I follow a example code but i cannot create my database i dont know why, in the emulator in folder there is not any database.This is my code
This is my main activity

```
public class T5Compras extends Activity {

      private EditText myEditText;
private ListView myListView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
private Cursor cursor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_t5_compras);


final ComprasDBAdapter comprasDBAdapter = new ComprasDBAdapter(this);


myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstBuying);

myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                comprasDBAdapter.open();
                comprasDBAdapter.insertProduct("jorge");
                myEditText.setText("");

                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;

    }
});

/*   ComprasDBAdapter comprasDBAdapter = new ComprasDBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
   comprasDBAdapter.open();
   cursor = comprasDBAdapter.getAllProductItemsCursor();

   cursorAdapter = new  SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lst_layout, cursor, 
           new String[]{ComprasDBAdapter.KEY_PRODUCT,ComprasDBAdapter.KEY_ID}, new int []{R.id.list_txtProduct,R.id.list_txtId });
  */ 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.t5_compras, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

This is my class

```
      public class ComprasDBAdapter {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "listCompra.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "productItems";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_PRODUCT = "product";
private ComprasDBOpenHelper dbHelper;



public ComprasDBAdapter(Context _context) {
// TODO Crear una instancia de ComprasDBOpenHelper.
// Inicializar el CursorFactory a null para utilizar el que
// el sistema tiene por defecto.


ComprasDBOpenHelper comprasDBOpenHelper = new ComprasDBOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 

}

public void close() {
       db.close();

}


public void open() throws SQLiteException {
try
{
      db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
catch (SQLiteException ex)
{
      db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
}
}
// Insertar un producto

public long insertProduct(String _product) {
// TODO
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("KEY_PRODUCT", _product);


    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    return 0;
}
// Eliminar un producto según su ID

public boolean removeProduct(int _id) {
//TODO
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "KEY_ID='_id'", null);
return false;
}

// Actualizar el producto

public boolean updateProduct(long _rowIndex, String _product) {
// TODO
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_PRODUCT, _product);
    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, "KEY_PRODUCT='_product'", null);
    return false;
}

public Cursor getAllProductItemsCursor() {
// TODO

return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM productItems", null);
}


private class ComprasDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public ComprasDBOpenHelper(Context context,
    String name,
    CursorFactory factory,
    int version)
    {

    super(context, name, factory, version);


    }
    // Sentencia SQL para crear la nueva base de datos.
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + KEY_ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_PRODUCT
    + " text not null)";
    @Override

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
    {

    _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    @Override

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
    {
    Log.w("ComprasDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +
    _oldVersion + " to " +
    _newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(_db);
    }




}
```

}

When I try to insert some values my application is crashed and the logcat said that the error is in there I supposed that is database becasue database is not created

That is the logcat

```
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.imaginagroup.t5compras.ComprasDBAdapter.open(ComprasDBAdapter.java:43)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.imaginagroup.t5compras.T5Compras$1.onKey(T5Compras.java:43)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7200)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-16 06:45:08.331: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the o/p of logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ComprasDBAdapter constructor from

```
public ComprasDBAdapter(Context _context) {
// TODO Crear una instancia de ComprasDBOpenHelper.
// Inicializar el CursorFactory a null para utilizar el que
// el sistema tiene por defecto.


ComprasDBOpenHelper comprasDBOpenHelper = new ComprasDBOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 

}
```

to

```
public ComprasDBAdapter(Context _context) {
// TODO Crear una instancia de ComprasDBOpenHelper.
// Inicializar el CursorFactory a null para utilizar el que
// el sistema tiene por defecto.


dbHelper  = new ComprasDBOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 

}
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(1066): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at com.imaginagroup.t5compras.ComprasDBAdapter.open(ComprasDBAdapter.java:43)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at com.imaginagroup.t5compras.T5Compras$1.onKey(T5Compras.java:43)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7200)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1066):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)

Comment: I changed my code, I eliminated method open that I had in the main activity and I changed my constructor too but nothing. The problem is in the part of insert!!I cannot create the dataase I do not understand why

Comment: Please don't give answers like this without saying what you changed and why.  Copy/paste programming teaches nothing.

Comment: @VictorSolorzano Please edit your question to include the logcat.  It's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: @Simon I agree with you regarding the copy/paste part and resist from answering in that format. However the changes are self-explanatory. And the error can be because of an oversight.

Comment: @VictorSolorzano The NullPointerException is in the open method and initializing the dbHelper in the constructor should resolve that (assuming the changes are done in the original code you posted). If you are still encountering an error, post your new code and the logcat output.

Comment: THe only changes that I have done is eliminate open method but the error is still nullpointer and in the constructor I do not know what I should do I saw other post and I am right

Comment: When you eliminated open method, the db is not initialized. Please revert to your original code and initialize dbHelper in the constructor as I suggested above.

Comment: Yes I put that line dbHelper  = new ComprasDBOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); in the code the same way that you told me but nothing!!

Comment: Have you reverted the open method and called it before insertProduct?

Comment: @Rajesh the changes are obvious to me and to you, but for someone learning, it says nothing.

Comment: the problem was the constructor..but i dont understahnd what is the problem to do dbHelper  = new ComprasDBOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); and ComprasDBOpemHelper comprasDBOpemHelper= new ComprasDBOpenHelper(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

Comment: @Simon Please see the comments in this answer. Even after so many instructions, the "learning" is not happening. People are happy if they can resolve their issues. Those who are here to learn would easily take the cue and understand their mistake. My answer addresses both kinds of users.

Comment: @VictorSolorzano what you originally did in your constructor was to create a local instance comprasDBOpemHelper which will cease to exist outside the constructor. Whereas dbHelper is a member variable which has the scope of the object. When you initialize dbHelper in the constructor, you can access it in other methods of the object.

Comment: So sorry for that mistake thank very much I am a begginer that want to learn about Java I admited that I want to learn a lot but with that mistake I dont go anywhere

Comment: @VictorSolorzano please do not get offended by my other comments. If you can learn something from this, that would be a plus. BTW, it would help you if you learn a little bit more about OOP & Java before you venture further into Android.